# How to print a variable to Linux console using Javascript and QWebview

Tags: javascript, linux, qwebview

Inside a function which IS getting called through Qt's QWebView:

```
document.write ("11");
```

The above statement doesn't show anything on the console!

I want it to get displayed on the "console". I am running the qt executable as "./showmap" and then **a widget gets displayed on which the map is shown**. On a button click, a function gets called and in that function I have written *document.write("11");* which doesn't seem to be doing anything normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what document.write does. It writes to the document.

To write to the OS's standard output or standard error, subclass [QWebPage](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qwebpage.html) and override [javascriptConsoleMessage](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qwebpage.html#javaScriptConsoleMessage).

Here is an example:

http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Redirecting_JavaScript_console_messages_in_a_Qt_hybrid_application

Once you've overridden javascriptConsoleMessage to write to the operating system's stdout/stderr (with qDebug), calls to console.log will write to stdout/stderr as well.

As an alternative, overriding javascriptAlert() and then calling alert() in your Javascript should do the same thing.

Comment: Thanks Dugan, but it didn't do what I wanted, see LQ. P.S. I'll edit the question now.

Comment: I'll add the reasons here too, just for the sake: I tried your method, that was indeed helpful in getting the "error messages".

But my question is how should I "print a variable" on the "Linux console" from Javascript functions. I am not talking of error messages here, I just want to see what the variables contain.

Comment: and bounty can't be awarded before 23 hours :rolleyes: